# SSH into EC2 Spot Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

It's my first time using an ec2 instance from the spot market. I'm assuming its the same to SSH into as with any normal instance. I submitted a request and got one back but now for some reason when I try to SSH into with the public IP I'm getting a timed out error. Is there anything else I need to do after submitting the Spot request, other than waiting for someone to fill it?

Comment: When you requested the spot instance did you pick the correct key pair? Is the spot instance in a security group with port 22 open?

Comment: I selected the right key pair, there's only one. How do I check for the port 22?

Comment: @MarkB Under the Instance Description, the Security Groups - View Rules states that all ports are open.

Comment: @MarkB You're right I had to add a SSH rule. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As many other users have commented, there are two things need to be done for ssh

1. assign an [aws key-pair](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html) when launching the instance
2. assign a [security group with ssh permission](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html)

To check whether these two conditions are met for your instance, you can go to the [aws EC2 Management console](https://console.aws.amazon.com), click on your instance at the instance tab, and check if there is a `Key pair name` associated with it, and whether the `Security groups` inbound rule contains port 22 tcp protocol.

If you launch with boto3, the command will look like this

```
    rc = ec2.create_instances(ImageId=ubuntu_64bit,                            
                              InstanceType='t2.nano',                          
                              MinCount=1,                                      
                              MaxCount=n_workers,                              
                              KeyName='my-key',                               
                              )
```

Here I used the default security group and I have added ssh permission to it.

When these conditions are met, you can log on to the instance using

`ssh -i /path/my-key-pair.pem ec2-user@ec2-198-51-100-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com`

Depending on the image you load, the user name could vary. Possible ones include `ec2-user`, `centos`, `ubuntu`, `root`.

Answer (score 0):

Timeout error for ssh means `port 22` on this spot instance isn't open to you. Check the security group and add your location IP, allowing access to port 22